# Не получается добиться точности от нейросети-классификатора текстов

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, nlp, естественный-язык

У меня есть нейросеть, которая классифицирует тексты по 14 темам. Данные имеют вид [Текст,Тема], обрабатываются в файле prepare_data.py. Далее я их векторизую в файле main.py и передаю на обучение нейросети (main.py). Здесь и возникает проблема, над которой я уже всю голову себе сломала: (прикрепленное фото) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь находятся все файлы: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4cVTrUqg1qqSpA

ChatGPT посоветовал использовать Dropout слои, регуляризаторы - их я использовала, с Dropout уменьшилось accuracy, val_accuracy не изменилось; с регуляризаторами мало что изменилось. Еще ChatGPT посоветовал увеличить объем исходных данных, но у меня их достаточно (я их прикреплять не стала, но файл csv после обработки занимает 52 МБ, а там только текст). Непонятно в чем проблема, просьба помочь, благодарна буду любой помощи

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть в вопросе код векторизации слов и код создания модели и ее обучения, а то так сложно понять где может быть проблема)

Comment: @Step1709 , интересующий вас код находится на яндекс диске, который я указала в вопросе) дублирую: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4cVTrUqg1qqSpA

Comment: я решил там данные хранятся, сейчас гляну код)

Comment: @Step1709, ну что там?

Comment: У меня боюсь не хватает знаний для оценки, я пока новичок в нейросетях, думал может быть смогу найти проблему, но не смог(